# hibernate Same table @manytoone reference in @embeddedid

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

I am trying to create an entity which is called Category. Categories are multi-level for Example:
I can have a category with name food which is the top level. Then I can have 2 more categories under this: Vegetable & Meat. The way this should be represented is in a single table like so:

| Name | parent |
| --- | --- |
| Food | null |
| Vegetable | Food |
| Meat | Food |

Name must be unique for each parent for example I cannot have another Name=Vegetable & Parent=Food.
I am trying to do this using @EmbeddedId:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CategoryId implements Serializable {
  private String name;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_name", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_parent", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Category parent;
}
```

.

```
@Table(name = "category")
@Entity
@Data
public class Category {
  @EmbeddedId
  private CategoryId id;
}
```

This gives me the following exception:
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Foreign key circularity dependency involving the following tables: category, category

Does anyone have a way of achieving this in hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate this ability I posted a working example on my [github](https://github.com/elimxim/so-hibernate-table-refs-itself). It took me a while. I hope this example will be useful to you. Let me know if you have any questions.